# Integrating mongodb with neo4j, is there any API that will link them?

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, graph-databases, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am working on a recommendation engine. The user data is collected  (Their friendship, locations, likes,education,...) and is already stored in mongodb. I need to recommend relevant products to these users. I am planning on using neo4j for the recommender engine for obvious reasons (ease of traversal between nodes, path information,..). The problem is that I have to first convert the mongodb data into neo4j nodes/relationships, process the data and send the results back to the mongodb database. The main problems is that we will end up maintaining two databases, something that the development team will not be happy. I have already looked into similar posts [mongodb-neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114997/using-mongodb-and-neo4j-together) and [spring data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643609/spring-data-using-neo4j-and-mongodb) but not sure what to make of them for this problem.
these are my questions
1- Is it worth it to add another DB just for the sake of a Recommendation engine(we are dealing with a large network), although neo4j is a perfect fit for such task.
2- I am using cypher for queries and don't know much about java, rest API and spring data. What kind of API should I use for mongodb-neo4j communications? My current solution is to use R and use it as the platform to connect to both mongodb and neo4j.
3- How about other graph databases, is there one that is ore fit to integrate with Mongo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found two ways to integrate mongodb and Neo4j. The first one was suggested by [ryan1234](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108902/ryan1234) using Gremlin together with Gmongo. The steps are as following according to this excellent [blog](http://thinkaurelius.com/2013/02/04/polyglot-persistence-and-query-with-gremlin/)
1- Download [Gmongo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gmongo/gmongo) and [Java mongo driver](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.9.0)
2- copy the two jar files under neo4j/lib directory
3- This is an example. suppose we have this collection (called follows) in mongodb

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ff74c4ae4b01be7d54cb2d3"), "followed" : "1", "followedBy" : "3", "createdAt" : ISODate("2013-01-01T20:36:26.804Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ff74c58e4b01be7d54cb2d4"), "followed" : "2", "followedBy" : "3", "createdAt" : ISODate("2013-01-15T20:36:40.211Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ff74d13e4b01be7d54cb2dd"), "followed" : "1", "followedBy" : "2", "createdAt" : ISODate("2013-01-07T20:39:47.283Z") }
```

from the Gremlin shell in Neo4j run the following commands.

```
import com.gmongo.GMongo
mongo = new GMongo() 
db = mongo.getDB("local")
db.follows.findOne().followed
x=[] as Set; db.follows.find().each{x.add(it.followed); x.add(it.followedBy)}
x.each{g.addVertex(it)}
db.follows.find().each{g.addEdge(g.v(it.followedBy),g.v(it.followed),'follows',[followsTime:it.createdAt.getTime()])}
```

and that is it we have created the equivalent graph in neo4j

Comment: In your snippet the line to link to neo4j is actually missing, but you're using the reference, plus `db.follows.findOne().followed` could be left out. 
So to get the snippet to work, you could replace line 4 by 
`g = new Neo4jGraph('/tmp/neo4j')`

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki

Gremlin!

Specifically designed to work with Neo4j/graph databases.  Also you can easily download GMongo and connect to Mongo as well.

Check out this article that describes how to interact with polyglot data in Gremlin:

http://thinkaurelius.com/2013/02/04/polyglot-persistence-and-query-with-gremlin/

Comment: @ ryn, In your opinion, Is there any other graph database that is easier to link to mongo or neo4j is a good option? thanks for the comments, I will look into it.

Comment: Nothing that I know of that will integrate directly with Mongo. Titan is an alternative to Neo4j.  http://thinkaurelius.github.com/titan/  If you use Gremlin, you're not connecting a graph database directly with Mongo. Instead you're bringing data back to the client that is running Gremlin and then working with the data there. It just so happens Gremlin has some syntax that is supposed to make graph traversals easier.

Answer (score 1):

For using MongoDB and Neo4j together there is now the [Neo4j Doc Manager](http://neo4j.com/developer/mongodb/#_neo4j_doc_manager) project which will automatically sync data from MongoDB to Neo4j, converting documents to a property graph structure.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution if we want to use R. The following R code, will get the data from mongodb

```
library(RMongo)
library('bitops')
library('RCurl')
library('RJSONIO')
mg <- mongoDbConnect("local", "127.0.0.1", 27017)
mongoData <- dbGetQuery(mg, 'follows',"{}")
```

The result will be as following

```
  followed followedBy                    createdAt
1        1          3 Tue Jan 01 15:36:26 EST 2013
2        2          3 Tue Jan 15 15:36:40 EST 2013
3        1          2 Mon Jan 07 15:39:47 EST 2013
```

The following R code will connect to Neo4j and create the graph. It is not efficient but it works

```
query <- function(querystring) {
  h = basicTextGatherer()
  curlPerform(url="http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/CypherPlugin/graphdb/execute_query",
    postfields=paste('query',curlEscape(querystring), sep='='),
    writefunction = h$update,
    verbose = TRUE
  )

  result <- fromJSON(h$value())
  data <- data.frame(t(sapply(result$data, unlist)))
  names(data) <- result$columns
   data

}

nodes<-unique(c(mongoData$followed,mongoData$followedBy))
nodes=paste("_",nodes,sep="")
nodes<-paste(paste("(",nodes,collapse="),"),")")

edges<-apply(mongoData[,3:2],1,function(x) paste("_",x,sep="",collapse="-[:follows]->"))
edges<-paste(edges,collapse=",")    

cmd<-paste(nodes,edges,sep=",")
cmd=paste("create",cmd)
query(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at **Reco4j**? It uses neo4j as underlying graph database. They have implemented few algorithms as part of project. Here is link [reco4j](http://www.reco4j.org/). The link is currently unavailable but I found the features good when I had visited the site.